# How to set scope for a user/role in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: node.js, wso2, wso2-api-manager, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 Identity Server , I tried to associate scope with roles/users so that I can authorize them the access to API's if the scopes match. 
But no place i can see that.
I am using node js in my back end.

I want to achieve something like below
app.get('/deleteUser', authenticate({scope:'admin'}), function(req,res){

So that only those users[tokens] having the scopes 'admin' should be able to access deleteUser .How to achieve this user/role mapping to scope in WSO2 Identity server?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether wso2 identity server support user/role mapping to scope. But for your use case I think you can use wso2 apimanager which handle role mapping with scope 
http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2014/06/oauth-20-scopes-with-wso2-api-manager.html

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Identity Server doesn't have a scope validation logic by default. You will have to customize using [OAuthScopeValidator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Extension+Points+for+OAuth#ExtensionPointsforOAuth-OAuthScopeValidator)

As @Jenananthan has already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41340408/676123), WSO2 API Manager could be used for your use case.